# Can I do the dot product of a scalar and a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Sorry this is a silly question

$1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 3 &2&1 \end{bmatrix}$ 
does this just equal $3 + 2 + 1 = 6$?

Answer (score 2):

No. The dot product is only defined for vectors of the same length.

You can multiply a vector by a scalar, but the result will be a vector: $1 \langle 3,2,1 \rangle = \langle 3,2,1\rangle$, or more generally, $a \langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle = \langle ax_1,\dots,ax_n\rangle$.

If you have the vector $\langle 3,2,1\rangle$ and want a formula that gives you $3+2+1=6$, you would dot it with the vector of all ones: $\textbf{1}\cdot\langle 3,2,1\rangle = \langle 1,1,1\rangle \cdot \langle 3,2,1\rangle = (1)( 3)+(1)( 2)+(1)( 1) = 6$.